# Sorting Posts Based On Meta Value Using AJAX

Tags: wp-query, loop, jquery, ajax

I am trying to short posts on frontpage/archive pages using AJAX. The AJAX call seems okay but nothing displaying.

Here is the JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".sbyp" ).click(function() {
        jQuery("#list-items-review").empty();
        jQuery(".ajaxloader").show();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: SHTR.ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "priceshortaction" },
            success: function(response) {
                jQuery("#list-items-review").html(response);
                jQuery(".ajaxloader").hide();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And, here is the function:

```
function price_shorter_callback() {
    $query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'smr_product', 'meta_key' => '_productprice' ) );
    ob_start ();
            if ( $query->have_posts() ):

                while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); 
                    smr_product_the_frontend_item();
                endwhile;

            endif;
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
       $response = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean();
       echo $response;
       die(1);
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_priceshortaction', 'price_shorter_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_priceshortaction', 'price_shorter_callback' );
```

The function `smr_product_the_frontend_item();` is just a callback to display the posts. Here it is at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ExsQi0m7).

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do **not** link to outside resources - put everything in your question that is needed to understand every single bit of it. If the outside resource is gone, your question is of no help for later readers. Thanks.

Comment: What is the response returning exactly?